# Change label color of venn diagram with venn with/whithout ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn-diagram

I want to plot a venn diagram using R. For this purpouse, I'm using *venn* package, because allows to accepts more than 4-5 groups (as the majority packages that I've found).

The problem comes when I want to change the colour of labels (inner and outer ones). I have not found any method to modify them. If I want to use a dark background, black labels (default color) are not visible. I would like to use another color for them.

Recently, *venn* package has a logical *ggplot* argument, but I think it's used only for path aesthetics. Using *ggplot = TRUE* would simplifies save process with *ggsave*, assigning the plot as a variable (it does not work with the *ggplot = FALSE*, but it does not accept the *custom_color* variable, and through the error.

This is an example code:

```
x = rep(1, 20)
d = data.frame('A'=x, 'B'=x, 'C'=x, 'D'=x, 'E'=x, 'F'=x)
custom_color = c('blue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink')

library(venn)
library(grDevices)

png(filename = 'venn_plot.png', width = 2, height = 2, 
    units = 'in', res = 150, bg = 'black')
venn(d, ggplot = FALSE, 
     zcolor = custom_color, col = custom_color, 
     opacity = .5, box = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

v = venn(d, ggplot = TRUE, 
         zcolor = custom_color, col = custom_color, 
         opacity = .5, box = FALSE)
v

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1848): fill
```

Comment: It's hard to find much on the venn package. I think the key is to pass aesthetic (`aes`) values for ggplot. `?venn` includes "Via ..., users can specify additional parameters, mainly for the outer borders of the sets, as specified by par(), and since version 1.9 it is also used to pass additional aesthetics parameters for the ggplot2 graphics." Maybe someone can explain how to do that.

Comment: Yeah, it was my first thought, but I cannot get it work in any way. I've tried to use ( aes ) to pass color values, 'x' or 'y' variables....with no success

Answer (score 0):

You can capture your venn diagram as a grid object and then modify the parameters of that object directly.  Here I'm turning the labels red and background black as an example.  `View` can be quite helpful in determining which parameters to change.

```
library(gridGraphics)
library(grid)
venn(d, ggplot = FALSE, 
     zcolor = custom_color, col = custom_color, 
     opacity = .5, box = FALSE)
grid.echo()
venn_plot <- grid.grab()
venn_plot$children$`graphics-plot-1-text-2`$gp$col <- "red"
venn_plot$children$`graphics-background`$gp$fill <- "black"
grid.draw(venn_plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your point. But I prevent automatic view plot inserting it between png() and dev.off(), but with your method, grid.echo() needs view the plot, and be positioned before png(). My code is used into a function, so...